# Encryption... almost works

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I wrote a simple script for a website called Codewars (here: https://www.codewars.com/kata/57814d79a56c88e3e0000786). The purpose of the function was to encrypt a string such that every second character would appear first, and then the rest of them. I tested many random strings of text; it worked for a while. But then, I tested a specific case with 17 characters: `"maybe do i really"`, and it resulted in a character being dropped (notably a space). Initially, I thought the issue was that the `.join` method didn't allow a double space in a row, so I attempted to make my own function to mimic its functionality: it did not solve the problem. Could anyone answer why this specific string loses a character and returns a wrong encryption? My jsfiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/MCBlastoise/fwz62j2g/

Edit: I neglected to mention that it runs a certain number of times based on parameter `n`, encrypting the string multiple times per that value.

And my code is here:

```js
function encrypt(text, n) {
 if (n <= 0 || isNaN(n) === true || text === "" || text === null) {
  return text;
 }
 else {
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   if (i > 1) {
    text = encryptedString;
   }
   var evenChars = [];
   var oddChars = [];
   for (j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
    if (j % 2 === 0) {
     evenChars.push(text.charAt(j));
    }
    else {
     oddChars.push(text.charAt(j));
    }
   }
   var encryptedString = oddChars.join("") + evenChars.join("");
  }
  return encryptedString;
 }
}

function decrypt(encryptedText, n) {
 if (n <= 0 || encryptedText === "" || encryptedText === null) {
  return encryptedText;
 }
 else {
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   if (i > 1) {
    encryptedText = decryptedString;
   }
   var oddChars = [];
   var evenChars = [];
   for (j = 0; j < encryptedText.length; j++) {
    if (j < Math.floor(encryptedText.length / 2)) {
     oddChars.push(encryptedText.charAt(j));
    }
    else {
     evenChars.push(encryptedText.charAt(j));
    }
   }
   var convertedChars = []
   for (k = 0; k < evenChars.length; k++) {
    convertedChars.push(evenChars[k]);
    convertedChars.push(oddChars[k]);
   }
   var decryptedString = convertedChars.join("");
  }
  return decryptedString;
 }
}
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = encrypt("maybe do i really", 1);
document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = decrypt("ab oiralmyed ely", 1)
```

```html
<p id="text"></p>
<p id="text2"></p>
```

Comment: *"I thought the issue was ... a double space in a row,"* - You are displaying the result in HTML, so multiple spaces get condensed back to one. Try testing with `console.log()`.

Comment: That's not an encryption. It's an obfuscation at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code itself. Basically HTML doesn't allow 2 or more spaces. You can use `<pre>` tag for the case like this.

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "<pre>" + encrypt("maybe do i really", 1) + "</pre>";
```

Comment: Huh, I wasn't sure my hunch was right. I never understood the purpose of `<pre>` until now. Tbh, I don't like the font, though. Any way to change it, but preserve the spacing?

Comment: Well, Since `<pre>` is HTML tag, you can adjust its style via CSS easily. For this case, you can try `"<pre style='font-family: font name you want'>"` etc.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm feeling stupid. I read that it displays it in a fixed-width font, so I thought that it couldn't be changed.